# Preprocessor directive: Why Identifier for header file with #define is not same as header file name

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Why inside myheader.h, we write:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H
...
#endif
```

Since, Identifiers are case-sensitive (lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct), and every character is significant. How the above is valid? It should be

```
#ifndef myheader.h
#define myheader.h
...
#endif
```

What is the purpose of the underscores? What if I have 2 separate header files with names: MyHeader.h and myheader.h, How does the preprocessor distinguish between these?

Comment: Read: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading underscore followed by uppercase indicates that it's either a name defined by the C++ implementation, because this form is reserved for the implementation, or it's a name defined by someone who has seen this in system headers and just copy-cat adopted it without understanding it.

Comment: So for user defined header files, we should not include the leading underscores?

Comment: @Nikhil: Right. Also avoid other reserved forms, which are (1) two successive underscores anywhere, or, (2) leading underscore in a name in the global namespace.